# How to correct 'datatype mismatch' error while importing the csv file into sqlite table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to import the following data into the sqlite3 table via *nodes_corrected.csv* file:

> id,lat,lon,user,uid,version,changeset,timestamp
>   26529519,12.9728616,77.6199745,Nagesh_Blr,1765920,34,26587371,2014-11-06
>   07:56:32.000

I have a schema:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    lat REAL,
    lon REAL,
    user TEXT,
    uid INTEGER,
    version INTEGER,
    changeset INTEGER,
    timestamp TEXT );
```

After I use the following code on the terminal:

```
.mode csv
.import nodes_corrected nodes
```

I get the following error on terminal:

> nodes_corrected:1: INSERT failed: datatype mismatch

Could somebody please help, I am stuck on it for a day?

Comment: Delete that first line with the column names from your file. If you import into an existing table, every row is treated as content. [Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import).

Comment: That indeed worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not solution for exatly this problem, but I recently struggled with importing CSV into sqlite3, maybe this will be useful for somebody, to import to SQLite make 100% sure that:

1. CSV file does not have any column names
2. CSV file must have encoding: UTF-8
3. In SQLite3 type

```
.mode csv
.separator ,
.import csvfilepath tablname
```

I'm intentinally responsing old question because I didn't find answer.